# adjusting JPEG compression levels with an Automator Service and sips - stumbles over certain file names

Tags: bash, automator, sips

I've been tinkering with a script that uses **sips** to adjust JPEG file compression conveniently from within the Finder as a **Service**. It maintains file stamps unlike the simple Automator compression/rescaling functions.

Alas, it stumbles over certain file names, e.g. ones with a space and doesn't rescale them presumably because the file output chokes on the space character. So, it proceeds as expected on a file like "*DSC03761.JPG*" but not on "*DSC03761 2.JPG*". It also fails if the path contains spaces, if for example the file resides in a folder called "*my Pictures*".

Since I'm a noob, I haven't figured out how to adjust the script. You probably have a better idea?

[screenshot of script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HEUXt.png)

bash script below:

```
for f in "$@"; do

# Save creation date time stamp of the target file in 't'.
  t="$(/usr/bin/GetFileInfo -d "$f")"

# Compress the target file. Level 0-100 or low/normal=50/high/best
  filename=$f
  #/usr/bin/sips --setProperty formatOptions 60 $f --out ${filename%.*}.jpg
  /usr/bin/sips --setProperty formatOptions normal $f --out ${filename%.*}.jpg

# Set the modified and creation date time stamps to 't'.
  /usr/bin/SetFile -m "$t" "$f"
  /usr/bin/SetFile -d "$t" "$f"

done

# Notify user that operation is finished with a sound.
/usr/bin/afplay "/System/Library/Sounds/Purr.aiff"
```

Comment: Quote variables with `"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, you correctly but unnecessaily quote an expansion:

```
  t="$(/usr/bin/GetFileInfo -d "$f")"
```

But here, where you would need to use quotes, you don't:

```
  /usr/bin/sips --setProperty formatOptions 60 $f --out ${filename%.*}.jpg
```

The latter should be

```
  /usr/bin/sips --setProperty formatOptions 60 "$f" --out "${filename%.*}.jpg"
```

Comment: Excellent, that did it. Thanks for straightening out my quotes.